# JavaScript Number Sorting Code Explanation

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am going through below descending number sorting code and getting confused:

```
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
points.sort(function(a, b){return b - a});
```

The above code will return (b-a) eg. 100- 40 = 60
but we dont have 60 in the array.

Comment: Go read up on how the `sort` method works, and what _meaning_ the value returned by the callback function has in the sorting process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From Mozilla Implementation of Sorting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)  -

1. If compareFunction(a, b) is less than 0, sort a to an index lower than b, i.e. a comes first.
2. If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.
3. If compareFunction(a, b) is greater than 0, sort b to an index lower than a, i.e. b comes first.
4. compareFunction(a, b) must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined.

You can simple check how the function is working by adding some logs.

```
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
points.sort(function(a, b){
console.log("a = " + a + 
        ": b= " + b + 
        ": b - a = " + (b - a) + 
        " swap a and b if b-a > 0");
return b - a});
```

Output -

```
a = 40: b= 100: b - a = 60 swap a and b if b-a > 0 
a = 40: b= 1: b - a = -39 swap a and b if b-a > 0 
a = 1: b= 5: b - a = 4 swap a and b if b-a > 0 
a = 40: b= 5: b - a = -35 swap a and b if b-a > 0 
a = 1: b= 25: b - a = 24 swap a and b if b-a > 0 
a = 5: b= 25: b - a = 20 swap a and b if b-a > 0 
a = 40: b= 25: b - a = -15 swap a and b if b-a > 0 
a = 1: b= 10: b - a = 9 swap a and b if b-a > 0 
a = 5: b= 10: b - a = 5 swap a and b if b-a > 0 
a = 25: b= 10: b - a = -15 swap a and b if b-a > 0
```

Comment: @shashankpatil you can mark the answer as correct, if it helped you, so others can benefit as well.